# UITableView of UITableViews?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to create a UITableView of UITableViews. The idea is that the first UITableView holds tags, which map to queries. When you click on a tag, it should link to another UITableView of tweets, generated from searching twitter with the mapped query. When you click on one of the tweets, it takes you to a UIWebView showing the tweet in browser.

Is it possible to replicate this UITableView of UITableViews scheme? I know that you can get a UITableView of UIViews, but I wasn't able to get a TableView of TableViews working. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: A "table view of table views" would mean a table with another table displayed in each row. Is that what you want? Or do you just want a tap on one row of a table to transition to another table?

Comment: Correct. Each cell should link to another UITableView.

Comment: Check out the basic example of Master-Detail application!

Answer (score 0):

> Each cell should link to another UITableView.

People do this all the time. When the user taps one row, just determine what row was tapped, instantiate a new view controller with a table, pass it the data corresponding to the row, and push the new controller onto the nav stack (or segue to it, etc.).

If you're having trouble getting it working, post your code and describe what you think should happen and what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is very standard in iOS. You can easily build it using storyboards. I highly recommend [this](http://raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) tutorial which shows you how to do exactly what you are asking.